# How can I view the number of tables existing under one particular Owner?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to view the number of tables existing under one particular Owner/Creator.

How would I do this?

---

#### Note:

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle or Microsoft SQL? Also when you say owner, do you mean the database?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845571/listing-all-tables-in-a-database do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

use yourdb;

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
where table_type like '%base table%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   table_schema, 
         COUNT(*)
from     information_schema.Tables
where    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
         AND table_schema = 'myschema' -- replace this with the schema/owner you are looking for
group by table_schema
```